# Visual Studio 2010 Property Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, properties

In earlier versions of visual studio, when I typed a property it would autofill the Get and Set methods. Now it just gives me the shorthand.

```
Public Property DataValueField As String
```

vs

```
Public Property AutoPostBack As Boolean
    Get
        Return blnAutoPostBack
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        blnAutoPostBack = value
    End Set
End Property
```

How can get the old longhand back?

(I have the following extensions installed which could be getting in the way: Productivity Power Tools, Viasfora, Visual Studio Color Theme Editor)

Comment: `Public Property DataValueField As String` is all you need now.  It is called an auto-implemented property.  It adds a hidden `_DataValueField` - backing member which you can still use   The rest of the boiler plate will show up if you type `Get` and press enter.

Comment: @Plutonix gotcha. Is there anyway to get the old behavior back, though?

Comment: No.  They are here to stay (thats a good thing).  On the line below, you can type `Get` and press enter to roll back the clock 6 years.

Comment: @Plutonix Mmm party like it's 2009! You wanna make your comment an answer and I'll accept it?